# Prevent Internet access when VPN fails

Tags: vpn, iptables

Consider the following scenario:

The VPN server is a FritzBox 7590 with the latest OS and VPN configured as IPSec.

I have two locations that I connect via a VPN as follows. Location A runs a VPN server and Internet gateway (on `192.168.2.1`) that devices in location B can connect to. Location B has a simple Internet gateway (on `192.168.1.1`) and a WiFi network for my devices to connect to the Internet.

Now, I want SOME devices in location B to normally access the Internet (i.e. directly via the Internet gateway of location B). For other devices, I need to make sure that they use (without exceptions) the Internet gateway of location A (i.e. via the VPN) to access the Internet. **It is absolutely paramount that no traffic from these devices "leaks" to the Internet via the gateway in location B**. Let's call these devices "special devices".

As I don't want to configure a VPN connection for all the devices, I added a RaspberryPi to location B that functions as a (second) WiFi hotspot (on `192.168.5.1`) and at the same time establishes a VPN connection to the VPN server in location A. All traffic of all devices that connect to this second WiFi hotspot ("special wifi") therefore have their traffic automatically tunneled through to the IPSec-VPN server in location A, from where they can access the Internet. This works as intended with the following configuration for the RaspberryPi:

- **General setup**:

  The RaspberryPi runs RasberryPi OS lite 64bit (Kernel 6.1) and is connected to the Internet gateway of location B via ethernet (cable) and has a static IP address configured.
- **VPN configuration**:

  I use `vpnc` to establish the VPN connection. The configuration of the `/etc/vpnc/default.conf` looks like this:

  ```
  IPSec gateway my.awesome.vpn.server.com
  IPSec ID username
  IPSec secret p4ssw0rd
  IKE Authmode psk
  Xauth username Xusername
  Xauth password Xp4ssw0rd
  ```
- **Wi-Fi config:**

  I used NetworkManager (`nmcli`) to setup the hotspot:

  ```
  sudo nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid specialwifi   password p4assw0rd
  ```

  and then starting it with

  ```
  sudo nmcli device up wlan0
  ```

  Now, when I start the VPN connection and connect any device to the special Wi-Fi, their traffic is automatically routed as expected.

**Now to my question/problem**:

In case anything happens to the VPN connection, traffic from special devices would be routed "normally" via location B's gateway, i.e. not as intended. I need to prevent this!

Specifically, I am considering the following cases:

- The VPN connection breaks down
- The VPN client `vpnc` crashes
- The VPN server crashes

Any good advice how to approach this? I was thinking of configuring IP-tables but have no clue on how to do this right for the described setup. Unfortunately, I cannot configure anything on the "normal" gateway of location B.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle this depending on some nuances in your setup.

I am assuming here that you are worried about the vpn failing and not the end clients connecting to tje wrong ssid (or on ethernet).

- You could set the default route on the pi to lo so that, by default, traffic never goes through it.  You then need to specify a route via the WAN traffic to VPN A's endpoint should go through the WAN interface on the PI, and also have the VPN server advertise two /1 routes to override the default route.
- You could add 2 iptables rules to first allow **forwarding** through the vpn interface and then drop all other forwarding.  This wont affect traffic from tje Pi, only traffic forwarding through it.  The rules will vary depending on tje specifics but maybe something like

  ```
  iptables -I FORWARD -j DROP
  iptables -I FORWARD -i ipsecif -j ACCEPT
  ```

*You could equally just set the default forwarding rule yo deny and add the ipsec allow rule.*

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for establishing what's called a
"kill-switch", which means killing the internet when the
VPN connection drops for some reason.

In OpenConnect itself this was proposed in the feature request
[add the Kill-switch feature](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/-/issues/61)
but was never implemented.
The user Daniel Lenski made this comment that included some
practical advice:

> As far as OpenConnect is designed, this function is outside the scope of OpenConnect itself. The OpenConnect binary _doesn't actually do any routing/NAT'ing/firewalling at all. It defers the routing configuration to a [vpnc-script](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/vpnc-script.html).

The github script at
[vpn-kill-switch](https://github.com/germeuser/vpn-kill-switch)
can help and is described as:

> Bash script that nukes network connectivity once a VPN connection drops.

Another source is the article
[What Is a VPN Kill Switch and How Does It Work?](https://www.privacyaffairs.com/vpn-killswitch/)
which explains the concepts and contains some scripts.
Of special interest are the scripts under the sections
"Kill switch using iptables" and "Kill switch using ufw".

Here is the iptables solution from the article:

> Make sure you back up the current iptables ruleset first. You can do
> that with
>
> ```
> iptables-save
> ```
>
> 1. Create a new shell script that contains the following ruleset:
>
>    ```
>    iptables --flush
>    iptables --delete-chain
>    iptables -t nat --flush
>    iptables -t nat --delete-chain
>    iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
>    iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i lo
>    iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o lo
>    iptables -A INPUT --src 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT -i wlp6s0
>    iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT -o wlp6s0
>    iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -d 198.51.100.0 -o wlp6s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194
>    iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -s 198.51.100.0 -i wlp6s0 -p udp -m udp --sport 1194
>    iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -i tun0
>    iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o tun0
>    ```
> 2. Save the created script as iptables-vpn.sh
> 3. Set the permissions.
>
>    ```
>    chmod +x iptables-vpn.sh
>    ```
> 4. Execute the script.
>
>    ```
>    ./iptables-vpn.sh
>    ```

Replace the IP addresses in the script with your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyhow, I do NOT want a "kill switch" as it implies that Internet access is (theoretically) possible for connected client devices (the "special devices" in the example) and is just not configured in this way. If I would go for a "kill switch" option, I'd then make sure (i.e. provable) the kill switch reacts in time.

Comment: The solution must make it impossible for the "special devices" to access the Internet via ANY OTHER WAY than via the VPN. To IP-tables-based solution posted above hence sounds like the right approach here

Comment: I added the iptables section to my answer.

Comment: The ruleset in the original article misses some relevant information apparently. E.g.: Interface wlp6s0 is the WiFi interface and tun0 the VPN. IP 192.168.0.0/24 is (probably) the subnet for the wifi the VPN is supposed to be accessed from, 198.51.100.0 the VPN server (?). Furthermore, the configuration targets OpenVPN connections (Port 1194) yet misses other mandatory ports for OpenVPN (TCP 500 and 1194). IPSec uses ports 500, 4500 (UDP) and 500, 4500 and 10000 (TCP). Will post my findings once successfully implemented and tested

Comment: Won't work as the VPN server's IP address is not static